# Should comments be invisible unless tagged?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I don’t think anyone who has participated in a meta site for a while hasn’t seen one or more instances of confusion, disagreement, and downright hostility over comments.

I recently blocked web comments on a whim using a mobile web script blocker, and I must say the improvement in focus while browsing questions was surprising.

If comments are *truly* **only** to suggest improvements, then should they only be visible to the OP, commenter, and “@“-tagged users?

Note: new users could and should continue to comment on their own posts outside these rules, this is much less of a problem for the site.

Further ideas:

- How about making them invisible to <10k-reputatiom users? This should retain some self moderation. How about 100 reputation instead?
- Could high volume duplicates be mitigated by having a prominent link to chat instead of comment “if you don’t have direct suggestion”? (My understanding is that currently most new users don't even know about chat until asked to join by a current user).

Comment: Users need [20 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) to chat. Most don't chat because they can't.

Comment: This question isn’t concerned with commenting on your own post, i dont think thats a problem for the site, no? Ill update the question to specify this.

Comment: Who are we talking to in comments usually, the OP, and the modal/median OP rep is 1.

Comment: As a sidenote, telling people to only downvote for certain actions won't do anything but cause more downvotes.  People very much dislike being told what to do.  Votes are used for dis/agreement on Meta, and they'll continue to be used for such, no matter what you ask for.

Comment: @DoritoStyle of course it ignores the core problem, the conversation we were having in comments right here was specifically about your idea of using chat instead of comments.

Comment: Useless comments should be easier to get rid of, not make them hidden by default.

Comment: @RobertLongson this is meta, which is entirely different! And we ARE workign to improve the question, why is why i’m updating it as we make good points, no?

Comment: The code of conduct does not address votes **at all**.  Votes are curation, not anything to do with being friendly or not.

Comment: @ale i agree, but that puts more strain on our overworked mods.

Comment: On Meta, you have to be prepared to accept criticism.  If you present a bad idea, or try to change the paradigm in an attempt to shield yourself from the consequences of disagreement, it doesn't do anything for you.  You seem to be receptive to changing the idea, but you don't seem to be willing to accept that this is a fundamentally bad idea.  If you're not receptive to that, why should those that disagree be receptive to it in the first place?

Comment: _"So far, for my trouble voicing an idea and engaging with to community, I’ve lost ~8% of my reputation, which i need to be able to participate on meta."_ So? People are showing what they think of your idea, **which is what votes are for**. Asking people to _not_ vote your idea down, when they think it's a bad idea, circumvents the basic workings of the site. You can keep editing this question, but I think your core premise is too flawed to be accepted. As long as you keep editing the question, it will keep coming to the top of the list, to be seen by more people who think it's a bad idea.

Comment: This is a fetaure suggestion, criticism would be an answer, not downvotes IMHO. I realize this is meta, but at this rate, i’ll be banished from participating at all. How is that welcoming? Anyway, thats quite off-topic, i’d be happy to discuss it in chat.

Comment: Criticism is also downvotes.  No one is obligated to present reasoning for disagreeing with you.  It'd be *nice*, sure.  But as we can see here, you're just arguing with those that believe it's a bad idea.  Which is why downvotes *don't* need comments, or answers.  Welcoming has nothing to do with it.  Voting has absolutely **nothing** to do with the Code of Conduct.

Comment: @fbueckert sorry, open a chat if you wish to continue, i’ve dug myself into enough of a hole here...

Comment: If you keep readding/editing your meta commentry the post will likely get flagged and locked by a moderator. Do read [voting is different on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Locking would at least stop the hemmoraging 

Comment: [You might find this useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: @fbueckert I've scoured meta since the day i joined. Thanks for the effort, but no that is not very useful. I truly believe This is a problem with the site, not with me, so i’ll be leaving shortly. No hard feelings.

Comment: A site should welcome input from new users, not let the system kill their account,

Comment: New users should also research, be receptive to criticism, and work *within* the system, not try to dictate how they feel it should work.  I suspect much of the reception you are garnering here is a response to how you believe downvotes should be used, instead of their accepted usage, along with this not being a very good idea.

Comment: @fbueckert agree to disagree. Good day sir/madam.

Answer (score 12):

If comments were invisible except to the commenter, the OP and moderators, the OP might well receive dozens of identical suggestions, which would surely be irritating both to the OP and a waste of the time of potential answerers writing duplicate advice.

We'd end up with the OP saying "why are you asking me the same thing as everyone else again and again, I know that already". Then we'd have to explain that only they (and mods presumably) can see all the comments.

Equally if the OP asked some follow up thing in a comment (assuming of course their comments are universally visible and you're not proposing to hellban their comments) they might well get lots of identical responses which again surely wastes everyone's time. We'd forever be telling the OP something someone else had already communicated and we'd not be able to upvote comments that do provide good advice or flag ones that are offensive.

New users would have a worse experience because rude and unhelpful comments would stay around longer.

Comment: Good point, I didn’t think of that. Please see my latest edit ablut chat and let me know what you think.

Comment: I am certainly not proposing to hellban their comments ;)

Answer (score 9):

Bad idea. This removes the whole ability for the community to moderate the site.

Say someone posts an answer. Someone else comes along and leaves a comment that the answer is wrong. The answer, however, is correct and the commenter is the one who is mistaken. Since only the author of the answer sees the comment, and they may believe the comment, they will delete their useful, correct answer.

Worse, someone writes profanity and invective in a comment. Sure, the recipient can report it and wait for a Moderator to deal with it, but if the comment is public the community would have gotten it deleted (possibly before its intended victim saw it).

This is not something Stack Exchange should do. It would make comments less useful.

Comment: Good point! Please see my edit the question and consider whether that changes things.

Comment: @DoritoStyle: It doesn't. There may be plenty of 10k users on large sites like [so], but there would be precious few on smaller sites.

Answer (score -4):

I do think this would discourage casual visitors from being chatty or flaming. Disagreeing with someone else’s comment often leads to much back-and-forth and gets moved to chat anyway, so **let's commit to what is already implied by the site design**.

Anything meant for general consumption (not for direct input to a question/answer poster) should go to chat (off-topic, but this may require making chatrooms more visible on the main site).